# Center text in a box

Tags: html, css

So I've been cracking my head trying to solve this.

I am trying to center text horizontally. If you look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ76J.png) image, you can see that the icons are perfectly centered whereas the text is all the way to the right of the box. For some reason using `text-align: center` is not working. How can I get the text to be at the center of the box?

```css
/* CSS Variables */
:root {
  --black: #282e34;
  --main-grey: #666666;
  --second-grey: #92999f;
  --main-white: #ffffff;
  --second-white: #f4f4f4;
  --blue: #0a9797;
}

/* Resets */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}


h2 {
  color: var(--blue);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content {
  background-color: var(--second-white);
  color: var(--main-grey);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

/* Icons */
.skills {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
  "hi ht"
  "ci ct"
  "ji jt"
  "gi gt";
}

.fa-html5, .fa-css3-alt, .fa-js,
.fa-github {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.icons-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--main-grey);
  text-align: right;
}

.fa-html5 {
  color: #f16529;
  grid-area: hi;
}

.fa-css3-alt {
  color: #369cd6;
  grid-area: ci;
}

.fa-js {
  color: #f1be21;
  grid-area: ji;
}

.fa-github {
  color: #666666;
  grid-area: gi;
}

#html5-text {
  grid-area: ht;
}

#css3-text {
  grid-area: ct;
}

#js-text {
  grid-area: jt;
}

#github-text {
  grid-area: gt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="content">
    <h2>Skills</h2>

    <div class="skills">
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="html5-text" class="icons-text">HTML5</h2>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="css3-text" class="icons-text">CSS3</h2>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-js"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="js-text" class="icons-text">Javascript</h2>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="github-text" class="icons-text">GitHub</h2>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since your employing flexbox you can use "justify-content: center" for the horizontal alignment of .icons-text

Comment: Thanks! I also realized I could have used "margin: auto" on .icons-text.

Answer (score 0):

*Removed code lines:*

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

*Changed code line:*

```
text-align: center;
```

**code after change:**

```
.icons-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--main-grey);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #282e34;
  --main-grey: #666666;
  --second-grey: #92999f;
  --main-white: #ffffff;
  --second-white: #f4f4f4;
  --blue: #0a9797;
}

/* Resets */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}


h2 {
  color: var(--blue);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content {
  background-color: var(--second-white);
  color: var(--main-grey);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

/* Icons */
.skills {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
  "hi ht"
  "ci ct"
  "ji jt"
  "gi gt";
}

.fa-html5, .fa-css3-alt, .fa-js,
.fa-github {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.icons-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--main-grey);
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-html5 {
  color: #f16529;
  grid-area: hi;
}

.fa-css3-alt {
  color: #369cd6;
  grid-area: ci;
}

.fa-js {
  color: #f1be21;
  grid-area: ji;
}

.fa-github {
  color: #666666;
  grid-area: gi;
}

#html5-text {
  grid-area: ht;
}

#css3-text {
  grid-area: ct;
}

#js-text {
  grid-area: jt;
}

#github-text {
  grid-area: gt;
}
```

```html
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
   
   <section class="content">
    <h2>Skills</h2>

    <div class="skills">
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="html5-text" class="icons-text">HTML5</h2>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="css3-text" class="icons-text">CSS3</h2>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-js"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="js-text" class="icons-text">Javascript</h2>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
      </div>
      <h2 id="github-text" class="icons-text">GitHub</h2>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is just add `justify-content: center;` to `.icons-text` like this

```
.icons-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: var(--main-grey);
    text-align: right;
    justify-content: center; // Added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help! I did find another solution to it. I removed `display: flex`, `align-items: center`, and `text-align: right`. I essentially ended up with this:

```
.icons-text {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--main-grey);
}
```